# create select box from array in grails

Tags: grails, groovy

I would like to populate a **drop-down**/**select-box** using `[[1, Room 1], [2, Room 2]]` array.

How can do it?

Here `1, 2` will be option key and `'Room 1'`, `'Room 2'` will be value.

Answer (score 0):

Turn the List of List into a Map:

```
<g:select ...
from='${mydata.collectEntries()}'
optionKey="key" optionValue="value"></g:select>
```